# Extract From CSV with specific multiple values

Tags: excel, vba, csv

so i have a CSV file that contains names location gender and email addresses, so i need to filter it to have only USA emails, is there a possibility to extract the emails based on raws that contains state or city of USA? so for example, in location column there is "Ely- Nevada" and i want to extract it, with one value it is not so hard, but how to do with several values like every state and city of the USA (i can get whole list here: https://www.britannica.com/topic/list-of-cities-and-towns-in-the-United-States-2023068)

So i have try CSVed program but it hard to put every country that i dont need and etc...

With this VBA code they are deleting raws with specific values :

```
Sub Delete_All_Rows_IF_Cell_Contains_Certain_String_Text()
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim iCntr As Long
    lRow = 1000
    For iCntr = lRow To 1 Step -1
        If Cells(iCntr, 3).Value = "Certain data to delete here" Then
            Rows(iCntr).Delete
        End If
    Next
End
```

is there possible to not delete but to save all raws but the values must be several, can some one help in this?

Comment: You are going to have to somehow reference everything you don't need (or do need).  I'd look at setting up an inclusive filter, and then copy the visible rows.

Answer (score 0):

One easy way would be to have a list of the locations you want to keep in a separate sheet, then add an extra column to your initial data, and do a `VLOOKUP` (or `INDEX/MATCH`), then filter and delete. For a one off process, that's what I would do.

For a vba solution, something like this, but you would still need that list of acceptable locations in a separate sheet:

```vb
Sub setDeleteNonUsa()
'Assuming 4 columns:
'A: [names]
'B: [location]
'C: [gender]
'D: [email]

Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ActiveWorkbook 'Alternative options: ThisWorkbook or Workbooks("book name")

Dim wsData As Worksheet: Set wsData = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Dim wsLocs As Worksheet: Set wsLocs = wb.Worksheets("Sheet2")

'Declare and set the variable to hold the last row values
Dim lRowData As Long: lRowData = wsData.Cells(wsData.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Dim lRowLocs As Long: lRowLocs = wsLocs.Cells(wsLocs.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'Declare and set an array to hold the current data (Column A:D, Sheet1)
Dim arrData As Variant: arrData = wsData.Range("A1:D" & lRowData) 'allocate the data to the array

'Declare and set an array to hold the acceptable locations (column A, Sheet2)
Dim arrLocs As Variant: arrLocs = wsLocs.Range("A1:A" & lRowLocs) 'allocate the locations to the array

'Process the data
Dim Rd As Long, Rl As Long
For Rd = UBound(arrData) To LBound(arrData) + 1 Step -1 'Iterate through each row of the data, skipping headings
    For Rl = LBound(arrLocs) + 1 To UBound(arrLocs) 'Iterate through each row of the locs, skipping headings
        If arrData(Rd, 2) = arrLocs(Rl, 1) Then Exit For 'location match, skip to next
        If Rl = UBound(arrLocs) Then wsData.Cells(Rd, 1).EntireRow.Delete 'we got to last one, no location match
    Next Rl
Next Rd

End Sub
```

Comment: Well i can load all the states and cities to another sheet... but how works that code above can you explain? thank you

Comment: Assuming you have 4 columns in sheet1, and the second column is the location, i run a match between those, and sheet2 column A. If no match found (i.e. not a location in the second sheet), delete the row. See comments through the code for more "how it works".

Comment: @karencho at what line? Try to step through the code, or hit debug when you get the error and see what's missing. I would assume you don't have 'Sheet1` or "Sheet2" from that error.